# Multiple selectors on Angular ng-content

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-content-projection

I know it's possible to have multiple `ng-content`'s with different selectors to project content into slots. e.g.

```html
<ng-content select="h1"></ng-content>
<ng-content select="span"></ng-content>
```

My question is, is it possible to have **multiple selectors** on the **same instance** of `ng-content`, e.g.

```html
<!-- this doesn't work -->
<ng-content select="h1, h2, h3"></ng-content>
<ng-content select="span, div"></ng-content>
```

similar to how you can have the same rule CSS for multiple selectors, i.e.

```css
h1, h2, h3 {...}
div, span {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this does work:

```
<ng-content select="h1, h2, h3"></ng-content>
```

however, this does not:

```
<ng-content select="[input], [form-field]"></ng-content>
```

You really shouldn't be doing that anyway, since if you're creating a custom attribute anyway, you should make it dynamic.

Comment: Your second example works fine for me. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059767/5253897) has a demo.

Answer (score 2):

`<ng-content select="[input], [form-field]"></ng-content>` should work!

#### awesome.component.html

```html
<ng-content select="[input],[form-field]"></ng-content>
```

#### even-more-awesome.component.html

```html
<awesome>
 <h3 input>Foo!</h3>

  <h2 form-field>bar</h2>

  <h1 input form-field>foo & bar!</h1>
</awesome>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqcw4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).